# How to filter male and female id in Facebook graph api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know how to check if id is male or female by

```
<?php
 //get the user gender 
        $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
        $user_gender = $user_profile['gender'];
        echo "Gender: " . $user_gender;
?>
```

but I need to get any 10 female ID or 10 Male ID ..(Not Mixed).Any Ideas Please?

ps: i don't want fql please

Comment: Random 10 ID's or 10 friends of `/me` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well your question is not very clear about from where your are trying the get user ids. 
**I am assuming that you want to seperate ids of your friends**.
First retrieve friend list:

```
$f=$facebook->api('/me/friends',array('access_token'=>$accessToken));
```

Then define two arrays: `male=new array();` and `female=new array();` . Loop to check gender of each friend:

```
foreach($f as $t){
   $usr=$facebook-api("/$t['id']");
       if($usr['gender']=='male')
           $male[]=$usr['id'];
       else 
           $female[]=$usr['id']; 
}
```

At the end of the loop you will have all **males and females in their respective array**.

Comment: Sorry if my code is unformatted. I just answered using my nokia 2690

Answer (score 3):

I know you said no FQL, but just in case you're not able to get a non-FQL answer:

```
SELECT sex, uid
FROM user
WHERE uid IN (
  SELECT uid2
  FROM friend
  WHERE uid1 = me()
)
AND sex = 'female'
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: There's no ability to filter on a field in the API. You'd need to return a whole bunch of users and filter them in your script if you don't want to use FQL.

Answer (score 0):

I develop an easy/clean code to solve what you're exposing, with only one request.

1. Create arrays (male, female)
2. Make request to get id and gender (?fields=id,gender)
3. Looping data and conditions (male,female)

```
    // Array Friends 
    $female_friends = array();
    $male_friends   = array();

    // Make request
    $friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends?fields=id,gender');

    // Loop
    foreach ($friends['data'] as $friend) {
        if   ($friend['gender'] =='female') female_friends.push($friend['id']);
        else ($friend['gender'] =='male')   male_friends.push($friend['id']);
    }

    // Show data
    print_r($female_friends);
    print_r($male_friends);
```